# How do I filter items returned by list to exclude files last modified by me?

Tags: google-drive-api

Looking at the results of list, there is a lastModifyingUserName, but not a userid or other concrete reference to a user such that I can strongly verify that the file was last modified by me or someone else.

I can approximate this behavior using a string comparison of my user profile information, but this isn't an exact check.

I also looked at the timestamps, and timestamps for a file that was modified by me don't seem to line up, so it doesn't look like I can do this using timestamps either, which looks like a bug in and of itself, e.g.:

```
    "modifiedByMeDate": "2013-01-31T02:25:26.738Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2013-01-31T02:29:58.363Z",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google are working on improving this so that there is consistency between the actor returned in the `lastModifyingUserName` field and the permission ID.

Right now I agree with you it is pretty impossible, sorry.

Comment: I have noticed this same issue with all sorts of other similar instances of users, such as document comments.